# Remove Event listener and move movie clip to position

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, event-listener

Im having some trouble getting the syntax right.

I have a movie clip that adds sounds to an array when it is touching other movie clips.
I have a stop button than i want to remove the event listener of the bar and send back to the original position.

My code is:

```
//event listener for the start button
playy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick2);

function mouseClick2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    bar.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);
}


//Add event listener for the stop button
stopp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick3);


//when clicked remove listener send back to position
function mouseClick3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    bar.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick3);

    function mouseClick3(evt:Event):void
    {
        if(bar.x > 780)
        {
             bar.x = 215;
        }
    }
}


function onEnter(evt:Event):void
{
    bar.x += 1;

    if(bar.x > 780)
    {
        bar.x = 215;
    }

    for(var i:int=0; i<blocks.length;i++)
    {
        if (bar.hitTestObject(blocks[i]))
        {
            blocks[i].start();
        }
        else
        {
            blocks[i].stopSound();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem you have is `function mouseClick3()` being nested within another `function mouseClick3()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your function should be this:

```
//when clicked remove listener send back to position
function mouseClick3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    bar.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick3);

    if(bar.x > 780)
    {
        bar.x = 215;
    }
}
```

The issue is that you have two "mouseClick3" functions in there. The inner mouseClick3 never actually executes, and the removeEventListener is going to target the mouseClick3 that never executes, since that is the variable local in the function. If you remove the inner mouseClick3, the code will execute and your listener will target the correct function.